# LaTeX doesn't recognise label for unnumbered section

Tags: labels, nameref

I'm fairly experienced with LaTeX and can usually solve bigger problems with a quick Google but this one is driving me mad.

In my thesis I have unnumbered sections. I am trying to refer to a subsection by *name*, using the nameref package.

In my preamble I have `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{nameref}` already loaded, and I have recompiled from scratch several times.

The section is defined as

```
\subsection*{Section Name}\label{sec:eor}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Section Name}
```

(I have also tried commenting out and moving the `\addcontentsline`, placing the commands in various orders, pretty much everything I could think of!)

In the text I try to refer to it using `\nameref{sec:eor}`, both before and after the section heading, but always get an error saying "suppressing empty link...". So the label is not recognised. The same error comes up just using `\ref{sec:eor}`.

Worst comes to worst I will just type out the section names, but I'd rather not since I haven't settled on the names yet.

TIA for any and all help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: it works in standard documents, so show a small but complete example so that we can see what you are doing to break it.

Comment: Default \label stores \@currentlabel and \thepage in the aux file (\newlabel).  Hyperref adds \@currentlabelname and \@currentHref, plus one free slot for future expansion.  You can create a custom \label to store about anything (see pgfplots legend).